# How can I set a value of a property without setter on a stub?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, stub

Can I set a return value of a setter-less property of a stub that is created by Rhino.Mocks?

For example:

```
public interface IMyMachine { string myProperty { get; } }

...

IMyMachine m = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyMachine>();

// implement in a way so that m.myProperty will return "Ahoj!"
if (m.myProperty == "Ahoj!")
 //do something
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
m.Expect(x => x.myProperty).Return("abc");
```

or if you use a stub:

```
var m = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyMachine>();
m.Stub(x => x.myProperty).Return("abc");
```

Comment: Is it different than this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78389/rhinomocks-correct-way-to-mock-property-getter